# Is any ultraproduct of $\mathcal{O}_2$ still nuclear?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Is it known wether any ultraproduct of $\mathcal{O}_{2}$, regarding an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, is still nuclear or not ?

Thank you all !

(references for this would be very much appreciated)

Answer (score 4):

Ultrapowers of non-type-I C*-algebras are never nuclear. Actually please have a look at [Theorem 5.1 here](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~mdaws/pubs/corr.pdf) for full characterisation of C*-algebras with nuclear ultrapowers. (I hope that you will pardon me using the characerisation of nuclear C*-algebras as amenable ones.) You need only implication (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2), and that $\mathcal{O}_2^{**}$ is not nuclear follows from Wassermann's characterisation of (C*-)amenable von Neumann algebras from the 1970s.

As mentioned by Gabor, the following argument is flawed as emeddability of every separable C*-algebra into an ultrapower of $\mathcal{O}_2$ is equivalent to the Connes Embedding Problem:

*Take a subalgebra of $\mathcal{O}_2$ isomorphic to the compacts. Then by the principle of local reflexivity an ultrapower of $\mathcal{O}_2$ contains $\mathcal{B}(H)$, so it cannot be nuclear.*

Comment: Could you explain your last sentence? There must be some kind of gap here; it is most definitely not known whether an ultrapower of $\mathcal{O}_2$ contains a copy of every separable C*-algebra.